# Is there a "cleaner" way to set the properties of a group of controls than this?

Tags: c#

Looking to learn a way to clean up this code. Is there any way to apply a defined "style" in c#? I am new and looking for ways to tighten up my programming. I would like to be able to define the margin, maximum value, orientation, step frequency, tick frequency, tick placement, and transitions to each slider in a more concise way.

```
        //Slider 1
        Slider Slider_1 = new Slider();
        Slider_1.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
        Slider_1.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
        Slider_1.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Slider_1.Maximum = 10;
        Slider_1.StepFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_1.TickFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_1.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
        Slider_1.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        Slider_1.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });

        //Slider 2
        Slider Slider_2 = new Slider();
        Slider_2.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
        Slider_2.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
        Slider_2.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Slider_2.Maximum = 10;
        Slider_2.StepFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_2.TickFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_2.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
        Slider_2.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        Slider_2.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });

        //Slider 3
        Slider Slider_3 = new Slider();
        Slider_3.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
        Slider_3.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
        Slider_3.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Slider_3.Maximum = 10;
        Slider_3.StepFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_3.TickFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_3.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
        Slider_3.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        Slider_3.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });

        //Slider 4
        Slider Slider_4 = new Slider();
        Slider_4.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 3);
        Slider_4.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
        Slider_4.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
        Slider_4.Maximum = 10;
        Slider_4.StepFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_4.TickFrequency = 0.25;
        Slider_4.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
        Slider_4.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
        Slider_4.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });
```

Comment: Have you heard about arrays? You must have, you’re using them in the code.

Comment: Is this WPF?  Or are you just asking for general C# advice?

Comment: If it's WPF, you can just use a style.

Comment: @codekaizen I need to add the controls programmatically. Isn't style used in the xaml?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. A style is just a way to generate the exact content you describe here. You can build the style programmatically even, then apply it to a set of controls programmatically. But it looks like you have a static style, and you could declare it and then apply it using a style selector.

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Slider Slider_1 = new Slider(); 
SetProperties(Slider_1,.....)


public void SetProperties(Slider slider,some other parameters)
{
    slider.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
    slider.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
    slider.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
    slider.Maximum = 10;
    slider.StepFrequency = 0.25;
    slider.TickFrequency = 0.25;
    slider.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
    slider.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
    slider.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });
}
```

Comment: What about using .NET 4's default parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If all the properties have the exact same value, you can build a function that creates a Slider object .. something like

```
private Slider GetSlider()
{
    var slider = new Slider() {            
        Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0),
        Orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
        Maximum = 10,
        StepFrequency = 0.25,
        TickFrequency = 0.25,
        TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside,
        Transitions = new TransitionCollection()            
    };

    slider.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1);
    slider.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });

    return slider;
}
```

Comment: I like. But why not make the method `static`?

Comment: There's no problem on making this method static, but I like static methods only for "util" classes. This method is class-specific (I think)

Comment: I guess it's a matter of taste, because it works equally well as an instance method. I just think it's easier to "see" that the method doesn't use any "state" of the current object when the method is declared `static`.

Answer (score 1):

you could do a method that recieves a slider and set the properties passed by parameter

```
private Slider CreateSlider(int columnProperty, Thickness thickness, short orientation
    int maximum, double stepFrequency, double  tickFrequency, short tickPlacement )
{ Slider slider = new slider
  slider.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, columnProperty);
  slider.Margin = thickness;
  slider.Orientation = orientation;
  slider.Maximum = maximum;
  slider.StepFrequency = stepFrequency;
  slider.TickFrequency = tickFrequency;
  slider.TickPlacement =tickPlacement 
  slider.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
  slider.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });
return slider

}
```

and use it passing the values

```
Slider slider_1 = CreateSlider(0, new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0), (short)Orientation.Vertical, 
        10, 0.25, 0.25,  (short)TickPlacement.Outside )
```

I assume some `types` of values (in the `enums` for example), you should put your correct `types`

Answer (score 1):

Use Factory Method to create Slider object passing all needed properties at once.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you need to create these sliders, an implementation of the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) would be appropriate here.  This would provide you a way to easily encapsulate and reuse the logic for creating an instance of a `Slider`.  It also could be extended to have multiple creation methods, should there be a need later for a different "style" as you call it.

Example

```
var sliderFactory = new SliderFactory();
var Slider_1 = sliderFactory.CreateSlider();
var Slider_2 = sliderFactory.CreateSlider(SliderStyle.AnotherSliderStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor, refactor, refactor.  This could all be extracted into a method.  The Parameters would be ugly as sin, but it will do the job.

Alternatively, use you use the factory pattern, but that might be overkill here.

Factory Pattern

An important facet of system design is the manner in which objects are created. Although far more time is often spent considering the object model and instance interaction, if this simple design aspect is ignored it will adversely impact the entire system. Thus, it is not only important what an object does or what it models, but also in what manner it was created.

Since most object-oriented languages and runtimes provide object instantiation (e.g. new, newobj, etc.) and initialization (e.g. constructors) mechanisms, there may be a tendency to simply use these facilities directly without forethought to future consequences. The overuse of this functionality often introduces a great deal of the inflexibility in the system, as the direct use of a language/run-time object instantiation function creates an explicit association between the creator and created classes. While associations are a necessary type of relationship in an object-oriented system, the coupling introduced between classes is extremely difficult to overcome should requirements change (as they always do).

> Since the need to reduce the inherent coupling associated with
>   instance creation spans systems, it was not uncommon to see the same
>   types of solutions being used in a variety of different applications
>   and frameworks. Formalized within Design Patterns: Elements of
>   Reusable Object-Oriented Software (Addison-Wesley Publishing Company,
>   1995), these solutions are known as creational patterns. Creational
>   patterns describe object-creation mechanisms that enable greater
>   levels of reuse in evolving systems.
>
> One of the most widely used creational patterns is the Factory. This
>   pattern is aptly named, as it calls for the use of a specialized
>   object solely to create other objects, much like a real-world factory.
>   In the following sections, we will examine the logical and physical
>   models of this pattern, as well as discuss one such use of this
>   pattern in the .NET Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a List, Use Object Initialization, Use a method with default and named parameters.

```
var sliderList = new List<Slider>() {
   CreateDefaultSlider(),
   CreateDefaultSlider(),
   CreateDefaultSlider(gridCol = 3), //example of customizatiom
};

public Slider CreateDefaultSlider(int gridCol = 0, int max = 10, float stepFreq = 0.25, float tickFreq = 0.25, int tX1 = 30, int tY1 = 12, int tX1 = 0, int tY2 = 0) {
   var slider = new Slider {
      Margin = new Thickness(tX1, tY1, tX2, tY2),
      Orientation = Orientatian.Vertical, //not sure these work with default params
      Maximum = max,
      StepFrequency = stepFreq,
      TickFrequency = tickFreq,
      TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside,
      Transitions = new TransitionCollection()
  };
   slider.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, gridCol);
   slider.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition());
   return slider;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this code but you could try a for...each loop. Sorry for the Vb but...

```
   For Each slider as Slider in Controls
            slider.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 0);
            slider.Margin = new Thickness(30, 12, 0, 0);
            slider.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            slider.Maximum = 10;
            slider.StepFrequency = 0.25;
            slider.TickFrequency = 0.25;
            slider.TickPlacement = TickPlacement.Outside;
            slider.Transitions = new TransitionCollection();
            slider.Transitions.Add(new EntranceThemeTransition() { });

    Next
```

At least you only have to set the properties once